# How to query documents with embeded array and sort them

Tags: mongodb, symfony, mongodb-query, doctrine-odm, odm

I have problem to query documents with embedMany.

These are my documents, where User embeds many Groups (that I call userGroups).

```
class User {

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

     /**
      * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
      */
     protected $name;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Group", strategy="setArray")
     * @var UserGroups[]
     */
    protected $userGroups;
}

class UserGroup {

    /**
     * @MongoDB\NotSaved
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Group")
     * @var Group
     */
    protected $group;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(type="date")
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $joinedAt;
}
```

These are DB documents in User collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56de151b821b16ac02310a25"), 
    "name" : "Some user name", 
    "userGroups" : [
        {
            "group" : DBRef("groups", ObjectId("5705157244ae89863aaeb725"), "some group name"), 
            "type" : "T1", 
            "joinedAt" : ISODate("2016-05-13T19:59:43.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "group" : DBRef("groups", ObjectId("571498f7821b16100c5bcc58"), "some other group name"), 
            "type" : "T1", 
            "joinedAt" : ISODate("2016-05-21T20:07:26.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "group" : DBRef("groups", ObjectId("57348618c67940a0528b4567"), "some other group name T2"), 
            "type" : "T2", 
            "joinedAt" : ISODate("2016-05-30T18:07:39.000+0000"), 
        }
    ]
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("287sd3d728as56dnsdu2hsds782nsdsd"), 
    "name" : "Some other user name", 
    "userGroups" : [
        {
            "group" : DBRef("groups", ObjectId("5705157244ae89863aaeb725"), "some group name"), 
            "type" : "T2", 
            "joinedAt" : ISODate("2016-05-13T19:59:43.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "group" : DBRef("groups", ObjectId("57348618c67940a0528b4567"), "some other group name T2"), 
            "type" : "T2", 
            "joinedAt" : ISODate("2016-05-30T18:07:39.000+0000"), 
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I query for users in `group` with `ID '5705157244ae89863aaeb725'` and type `"T1"`?
The following query in Users collection delivers both users and it should deliver only the first, which has group with `ID '5705157244ae89863aaeb725'` and type `"T1"`

```
{ userGroups: { $elemMatch: 
               { "group.$id": ObjectId("5705157244ae89863aaeb725"), "type": "T1" } }}
```

But cannot sort them by `joinedAt` field

Comment: what is expected document ? only this one which match criteria? `$elemMatch` - could be your friend in this case

Comment: The query you are using will return the whole user record and will have the `userGroup` with all the objects in it. If you will explain your required output, then we may help you.

Comment: ok, sorry, I edited my question. Please check

Comment: it seems that this worked:

{ userGroups: { $elemMatch: { "group.$id": ObjectId("5705157244ae89863aaeb725"), "type": "T1" } }}

Comment: what about if I want to add the query a sorting by joinedAt? {"userGroups.joinedAt": -1} not working as expected. It sorts according to joinedAt of any group

Answer (score 0):

to sort inner array field you need to use aggregation framework:
This example contains steps and you can remove them to see how document changes

```
var unwind = {
    $unwind : "$userGroups"
}
var match = {
    $match : {
        "userGroups.group.$id" : ObjectId("5705157244ae89863aaeb725"),
        "userGroups.type" : "T1"
    }
}
var sort = {
    $sort : {
        "userGroups.joinedAt" : -1
    }
}
var reGroup = {
    $group : {
        _id : {
            id : "$_id",
            name : "$name"
        },
        userGroups : {
            $push : "$userGroups"
        }
    }
}
var reShapeDocument = {
    $project : {
        _id : "$_id.id",
        name : "$_id.name",
        userGroups : 1
    }
}
```

> //step 1

```
db.coll.aggregate([match ])
```

> //step 2

```
db.coll.aggregate([match, unwind    ])
```

> //step 3

```
db.coll.aggregate([match, unwind, match,    ])
```

> //step 4

```
db.coll.aggregate([match, unwind, match, sort,  ])
```

> //step 5,6

```
 db.coll.aggregate([match, unwind, match, sort, reGroup, reShapeDocument])
```

1 and 3 are selecting only documents matching criteria, 2 - unwinds array elements to separate documents, 4 - performs sort, 5 and 6 are used to restore previous shape

Comment: thank you for the answer. I need to do it by using doctrine

Comment: [see this](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/issues/89) you casn use aggregation in a `command` wrapper, ask uncle google for: **doctrine aggregation mongo** @Fran